# Epoch Seconds-to-Date/Time conversion, without using C Library functions

Tags: epoch, ntp

I have implemented the epoch-to-Date/Time code, mentioned in a question posed as 
'Convert between date/time and time-stamp without using std library routines', by Barak Manos, on Dec 29, 2013.

I am having a problem with the computed day. The other computed values are fine. I am using NTP seconds, since epoch 1900. I tried using NTP seconds since epoch 1970, but, that doesn't seem to work well, so, I assume this code prefers epoch 1900 seconds.

I always compute a day, which is 1 less than the actual day. For example, today's date = 2018-12-10. I fetch a value = 3753407101, from an NTP Server.

The computed time (hh:mm:ss) is accurate, and the computed year and month are accurate, but, the day computes to 9, not 10. Using a calculator, I get same results.

Using a calculator:

```
UINT_32  epoch;
UINT_32  years;
UINT_32  year;
UINT_32  month;

const UINT_32  days[4][12] =
{
  //Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
  {   0,  31,  60,  91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335},
  { 366, 397, 425, 456, 486, 517, 547, 578, 609, 639, 670, 700},
  { 731, 762, 790, 821, 851, 882, 912, 943, 974,1004,1035,1065},
  {1096,1127,1155,1186,1216,1247,1277,1308,1339,1369,1400,1430}
};


//NTP Server 131.107.13.100 reply = epoch 1900 seconds = 3753407101.
date time->second = epoch%60;   //1.
epoch /= 60;                    //62556785.
date_time->minute = epoch%60;   //5.
epoch /= 60;                    //1042613.
date_time->hour   = epoch%24;   //5.
epoch /= 24;                    //43442.

years = epoch/(365*4+1) * 4;    //(43442/1461) * 4 = 116.
epoch %= 365*4+1;               //43442%1461 = 1073.

if (epoch >= days[year][0])     //1073 > (days[2][0] = (731)). year = 2.

if (epoch >= days[year][month]) //1073 > (days[2][11] = (1065)). month=11.

date_time->year  = years + year;                    //116 + 2 = 118.
date_time->month = month + 1;                       //11 + 1 = 12.
date_time->day   = epoch - days[year][month] + 1;   //1073 - 1065 + 1 = 9.
                                                    //day should = 10.
//NOTE - Using epoch 1970 seconds, 3753407101 - 2208988800 = 1544418301, 
//produces the same result, day = 9, instead of 10.
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm working with a 16-bit uP, and no kernel, so an algorithm, which doesn't rely on the C library, is just what I was looking for.
I'm working with UTC, GMT, for now, and not worrying with the timezone (-5 hours).

Thanks,

Steven

Comment: As far as I can tell, this code fails to handle leap years correctly (specifically, it assumes that every 4th year is a leap year and ignores the "if year is divisible by 100 then its not a leap year, unless it is divisible by 400" rule). As a consequence, I think it's wrong for 1900 (which was not a leap year), causing it to be wrong by 1 day for everything after the start of 1900. With 1970 as the epoch this bug wouldn't be noticed until 2100 (because 2000 was a leap year).

Comment: Even when using the epoch 1970 seconds, it gives the incorrect day. My company's product will only have a lifespan of 20 years, at the very most. So, the algorithm doesn't have to handle date/time, before today's date/time, and not beyond 20 years. I will see if I can fiddle with the code, and get a confidence level. This system is used in schools, which heavily depend on accuracy, regarding dates and times.